# Set HTML5 Date field Min value based on another HTML5 Date Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am trying to set the minimum date of an HTML5 Date input based on the value set in another HTML5 Date Input.

So if you select the 3 April 2020 in the first date field, the `min` value of the second date input would be 3 April 2020.

I have tried using the value of the first date input, but this doesn't work. Any suggestions would be great.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.getElementById("fDate").setAttribute("min", today);

function myFunction() {
  var minToDate = document.getElementById("fDate").value;
  document.getElementById("fDate").setAttribute("min", minToDate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="fDate" onBlur="myFunction()">
<input type="date" id="tDate">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change fdate to tdate

```
document.getElementById("fDate").setAttribute("min", minToDate);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("tDate").setAttribute("min", minToDate);
```

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.getElementById("fDate").setAttribute("min", today);

function myFunction() {
  var minToDate = document.getElementById("fDate").value;
  document.getElementById("tDate").setAttribute("min", minToDate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="fDate" onBlur="myFunction()">
<input type="date" id="tDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the mininum value to second datepicker, so you need to get that element:

```
function myFunction() {
  var minToDate = document.getElementById("fDate").value;
  document.getElementById("tDate").setAttribute("min", minToDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic doesn't work because you're setting min on `fDate`, not `tDate`.

You should also avoid using inline `onX` event attributes as they are outdated and no longer good practice. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead. The logic can be simplified further as `min` accepts a Date object, so you don't need to hack around a Date object to form a string.

It's also worth noting that the `min` setting does not stop the user entering a date *before* that value. It's only used for validation when the form is submit, as you can see in the following example when the `Submit` button is clicked.

```js
let fDate = document.querySelector('#fDate');
let tDate = document.querySelector('#tDate');

fDate.addEventListener('change', function() {
  tDate.min = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="date" id="fDate" />
  <input type="date" id="tDate" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```